# Qt (C++), Add automatically a character after writing 2 chars (live editing)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm quite new on Qt softw.
I would like to make a small program, for my internship.
I've made a textedit object for write a MAC Address (17 chars max so.).
I want that after writing 2 chars, when you write the third one, it automatically put a : before write the third char.

DC:R
   ^
so when you press R it puts before automatically the :.

I Hope I'm clear.

Comment: You also better  include your code, textedit ...etc

Comment: Actually thats useless to put some code, I've didn't test because I don't know where to start to make it, I was thinking about a tick that checks the textedit everytime.

Comment: But without showing some effort to write your code, even if it does not work, its less likely that you get attention and an answer.

Comment: As i said, I don't know where to start! Thats why i'm explaining it on my post, you can imagine it like the windows license activation xD, after some characters it add automatically the  -  character, I want the same system, but for mac, so when you write your mac address it just automatically add a : every 2 chars

Comment: You can start in QT Creator .. go to examples .. there are so many, search for _textedit_ or any area of interest, these are free examples, you see the source code and you can run it ..

Comment: If i'm there that's because i've searched

Comment: OK. then your issue can easily be solved with QT _signal/slot_ architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use QLineEdit instead of QTextEdit and use setInputMask function of QLineEdit to set a format;

```
setInputMask("HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH;_");
```

Take a look at [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop)